# How to click the button on Visa exchange rate calculator using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, shadow-root

The revised the code from Shawn's answer to the question below to fill in another hidden field, Bank Fee.

[How to find and fill in the hidden currency input field on a Visa exchange rate calculator using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76364176/how-to-find-and-fill-in-the-hidden-currency-input-field-on-a-visa-exchange-rate)

[The filed I want to fill in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUjgK.jpg)

However, after I revised the figure and performed the click on Calculate Conversion button, I received a  ElementNotInteractableException warning.

[The warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc5FR.jpg)

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://usa.visa.com/support/consumer/travel-support/exchange-rate-calculator.html')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
accept_button_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Accept']")))
accept_button_element.click()

shadow_root = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//dm-calculator").shadow_root

enter_amount = shadow_root.find_element(By.ID, "input_amount_paid")
enter_amount.send_keys("1")

from_dropdown = shadow_root.find_element(By.ID, "autosuggestinput_from")
from_dropdown.click()
shadow_root.find_element(By.ID, "listbox-item-157").click()

to_dropdown = shadow_root.find_element(By.ID, "autosuggestinput_to")
to_dropdown.click()
shadow_root.find_element(By.ID, "listbox-item-0").click()

fee_edit = shadow_root.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'vs-link-cta.vs-calculator-edit-link')
fee_edit.click()

bank_rate = to_dropdown = shadow_root.find_element(By.ID, "input_bank_rate")
bank_rate.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
sleep(2)
bank_rate.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
bank_rate.send_keys('0')

# clicks on Calculate Conversion button
shadow_root.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'vs-btn.vs-btn-primary').click()
```

Is there any way to make it work?

I tried to use the mouse action but it didn't work.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error is generated from the last line in your code which is :

```py
# clicks on Calculate Conversion button
shadow_root.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'vs-btn.vs-btn-primary').click()
```

Replace it with the below line to make it work:

```py
# clicks on Calculate Conversion button
shadow_root.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.vs-container')[-1].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')[0].click()
sleep(5)
```

First, we find the `last` element with the class `vs-container` inside the `shadow_root` because it contains the `Calculate Conversion` button and then inside it, there are two buttons `Calculate Conversion` and `Reset`. So we click on the first button.

I hope this solves your problem!